# ParameterError: Audio buffer is not finite everywhere

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, librosa

While using the following code on one of the sound files of Urban Sound Dataset,

```
s, r = librosa.load(train_filename[7543])
tonnetz = librosa.feature.tonnetz(y = librosa.effects.harmonic(s), sr = r)
```

I get the following warnings and `ParameterError`,

```
E:\installed_python_anaconda\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py:1467: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less if np.any(X < 0) or np.any(X_ref < 0):
E:\installed_python_anaconda\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py:1479: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in maximum Z = np.maximum(X, X_ref).astype(dtype)
E:\installed_python_anaconda\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py:1480: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less bad_idx = (Z < np.finfo(dtype).tiny)


ParameterError: Audio buffer is not finite everywhere
```

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Feels like you're getting NaN or inf in your data. Check `s` and harmonics of it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered with this problem as well. The `utils.py` in librosa package has validation functions like this:

```
Returns
-------
valid : bool
    True if all tests pass

Raises
------
ParameterError
    If `y` fails to meet the following criteria:
        - `type(y)` is `np.ndarray`
        - `y.dtype` is floating-point
        - `mono == True` and `y.ndim` is not 1
        - `mono == False` and `y.ndim` is not 1 or 2
        - `np.isfinite(y).all()` is not True
```

and `np.isfinite(y).all()` is one of the validations. So if the numpy array `y` is not finite everywhere, which means `y` has `INF`, `NaN` or something similar, python will raise the exception above. Just check the numpy variables you used above and modify their infinite parts.

I hope this will be helpful to you.